# Laravel: Reset auto increment before re-seeding a table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is there a way to set auto increment back to 1 before seeding a table?

I empty the table before seeding it and if I didn't do `migrate:refresh` before seeding it then it continues the auto increment of the ID from the last position, e.g., 4.

Table seed:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('products')->delete();
    // Product table seeder
    $product = new \App\Product([
        'category_id' => 1,
        'image_path' => '/images/products/1/000001.jpg',
        'title' => 'test',
    ]);
    $product->save();
}
```

Creating the table:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->string('image_path');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

DB::table('products')->truncate();
```

Instead of

```
DB::table('products')->delete();
```

Comment: Adding `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');` at the beginning and adding `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');` at the end of the seed, and changing `DB::table('products')->delete();` to `DB::table('products')->truncate();` did it.

Comment: Your question only asks for the re-seeding of the table so @Rimon Khan assumes that this is only for PRIMARY KEY. Overall, up-voted the answer since this satisfies the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `make:migration` or `make:model -m` commands to create a migration, Laravel is creating `down()` method with [`dropIfExists()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables) clause:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('products');
}
```

So when you run `migrate:refresh` command, Laravel will drop the table and will recraete it for you.

Also, you have foreign keys in the table, so you need to use `dropForeign()` first:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('products_category_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::dropIfExists('products');
}
```

Comment: The "Laravel" way to do this, most definitely.